# Printing square pattern in Java -- off by one error

Tags: java, loops

I would to print the following pattern but I don't get the first column and the first row, which I don't really understand. Maybe an off by one error, but how to correct it ? Thanks for explanation.

The expected output :

```
00 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
01 11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81 91
02 12 22 32 42 52 62 72 82 92
03 13 23 33 43 53 63 73 83 93
04 14 24 34 44 54 64 74 84 94
05 15 25 35 45 55 65 75 85 95
06 16 26 36 46 56 66 76 86 96
07 17 27 37 47 57 67 77 87 97
08 18 28 38 48 58 68 78 88 98
09 19 29 39 49 59 69 79 89 99
```

The code :

```
public static void main (String args[]) {  

    for(int row=0;row<9;row++){
        int x;
        x=row;
        x++;

        for(int col=0;col<9;col++){
           x = x+10;   
           StringBuilder mySB = new StringBuilder(x+" ");
           System.out.print(mySB);   
        }

        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

Comment: because you're `x++` in the first loop. when the print statement fires, you're starting at `x=1` instead of `x=0`. so instead of 0,10,20,etc.., you get 1,11,21,etc...

Comment: For improvement you could do `for(int col=0;col<=100;col+10){` in your second loop and use the value of col instead of adding 10 every loop.
So `System.out.print(row + col);`. With this trick, you can loose the x completely and have a much cleaner code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put `x = x + 10` after you print, and remove the `x++;` line.

You also need to go to `<=9` or `<10` because you're missing the 9s:

```
public static void main (String args[]) {  

    for(int row=0;row<10;row++){
        int x;
        x=row;

        for(int col=0;col<10;col++){ 
           StringBuilder mySB = new StringBuilder(x+" ");
           System.out.print(mySB);   
           x = x+10;  
        }

        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

---

**Edit**
 Nifty Java 8 way of doing it:

```
private static class Grid {

    public static void outputGrid() {
        IntStream
            .range(0, 10)
            .mapToObj(Grid::generateRow)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static String generateRow(int row) {
        return IntStream
            .range(0, 10)
            .mapToObj(col -> String.format("%d%d", col, row))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    }
}

public static void main(String []args){
   Grid.outputGrid();
}
```

Comment: That will print something similar but not equal:

    0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 
    1 11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81 
    2 12 22 32 42 52 62 72 82 
    3 13 23 33 43 53 63 73 83 
    4 14 24 34 44 54 64 74 84 
    5 15 25 35 45 55 65 75 85 
    6 16 26 36 46 56 66 76 86 
    7 17 27 37 47 57 67 77 87 
    8 18 28 38 48 58 68 78 88

Comment: @Jason I can't format output well on comments, but first column lacks zeros (I took your last edited code).

Comment: I understand. I figured this was homework so I didn't want to give away the farm; just wanted to give enough to solve op's issue.

Answer (score 2):

How about like this:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        System.out.print(Integer.toString(y) + Integer.toString(x) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

```
00 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 
01 11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81 91 
02 12 22 32 42 52 62 72 82 92 
03 13 23 33 43 53 63 73 83 93 
04 14 24 34 44 54 64 74 84 94 
05 15 25 35 45 55 65 75 85 95 
06 16 26 36 46 56 66 76 86 96 
07 17 27 37 47 57 67 77 87 97 
08 18 28 38 48 58 68 78 88 98 
09 19 29 39 49 59 69 79 89 99
```

Comment: That'll print 00 01 02 03 ... Not the desired output.

Comment: Just caught that. Thanks... Updated.

Comment: It'll print the same. You should do `y + 10` in your loop and loose the toString.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Stack1
{

public static void main (String args[]) {  

    StringBuilder mySB = new StringBuilder() ;
    //You need to print 10x10 matrix 
    for(int row=0 ; row<10 ; row++){
        int x;
        x=row;

        for(int col=0;col<10;col++){
           if (x < 10)  //for first row
               mySB = new StringBuilder(0+""+x+" ") ;
           //for other rows
           else
               mySB = new StringBuilder(x+" ") ;
           System.out.print(mySB);   
           x = x+10;  
        }

        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

}

Output:

00 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
01 11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81 91
 
02 12 22 32 42 52 62 72 82 92
 
03 13 23 33 43 53 63 73 83 93
 
04 14 24 34 44 54 64 74 84 94
 
05 15 25 35 45 55 65 75 85 95
 
06 16 26 36 46 56 66 76 86 96
 
07 17 27 37 47 57 67 77 87 97
 
08 18 28 38 48 58 68 78 88 98
 
09 19 29 39 49 59 69 79 89 99

Answer (score 0):

[java8](/questions/tagged/java8) solution:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 9)
                .forEach(i -> IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 9)
                        .mapToObj(j -> j == 9 ? Integer.toString(j) + Integer.toString(i) + "\n" : Integer.toString(j) + Integer.toString(i) + "  ")
                        .forEach(System.out::print)
                );
```

Output:

```
00  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90
01  11  21  31  41  51  61  71  81  91
02  12  22  32  42  52  62  72  82  92
03  13  23  33  43  53  63  73  83  93
04  14  24  34  44  54  64  74  84  94
05  15  25  35  45  55  65  75  85  95
06  16  26  36  46  56  66  76  86  96
07  17  27  37  47  57  67  77  87  97
08  18  28  38  48  58  68  78  88  98
09  19  29  39  49  59  69  79  89  99
```